# How to get value of programmatically created NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#

I have program which creates multiple NumericUpDowns depending on user input (1-5).  I know how to get total value but how can I get value of each individual NumericUpDown. I was trying to test this using label1 but I get NullReferenceException error.

```
   NumericUpDown test= new NumericUpDown();
    test.Name = "mynum" + Convert.ToString(count2);
    numericUpDown.Add(test);
    System.Drawing.Point i = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 20+ i * 25);
    test.Location = i;
    test.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(test);
    test.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(mytotal);
```

NullReferenceException error is thrown at this line.

```
label1.Text = test.Controls["mynum0"].Text;
```

Comment: just add handlers for your test-events like you did for your 'assValue' (nicename btw ;) )

Comment: for a null reference, you should really post the stack trace so we know which line threw the exception

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're trying to do here.  The last lines don't seem to have anything to do with the first.  Can you re-edit just focusing on what you want to do with the UpDowns?

Comment: last line calls variable, which caluclates total

Comment: I copied wrong from my project test has event handler

Comment: what is "test0", what is myTotal, what is numericUpDown, what is i? On what line is the exception being thrown? We're still miles away from understanding what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

```
 test.Name = "mynum" + Convert.ToString(count2);
```

You named it "mynum" plus a number.  So you can't find it back with test.Controls["test0"].  Fix the indexer argument to "mynum0" or the Name property assignment.

The next problem you have is that the NumericUpDown control doesn't have a functional Text property.  It uses Value instead, a number instead of a string.  So you'll need to cast the control to NumericUpDown to access the Value property.

```
 var nud = this.Controls["mynum0"] as NumericUpDown;
 if (nud == null) throw new Exception("I can't do that Dave, it isn't there");
 label1.Text = nud.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Your original problem was easy to explain, the code was obviously wrong.  Whatever *other* problem you have is difficult to guess.  Use the debugger and look at the test.Controls variable to see what controls are actually present.

Comment: Well it seems I can't get text from numberupdown just value, and Control doesn't recognise value argument instead of text?

Comment: It still throws exception as nud seems to be null. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Use the debugger, I can't help you beyond this point.  It is completely unclear where "test" came from.