# NumericUpDown not showing value

Tags: c#

I am resetting my form controls. 
After programatically chaging the value of `NumericUpDown` Control, it is not showing the value.
It actually changes the value but the text on the control remains blank.

This is my code

```
public void ResetFields(Control.ControlCollection Controls)
{
foreach(Control control in Controls)
{
   if (control is TextBox)
   {
      control.Text = string.Empty;
   }
   if (control is NumericUpDown)
   {
      NumericUpDown updown = control as NumericUpDown;
      updown.Value = 3;
   }

   if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
   {
      this.ResetFields(control.Controls);
   }
}
}
```

I have got the solution and have posted it as the answer.

Comment: Try adding "this.Show();" after this loop.  Good odds you'll now see it.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried updown.show() but it didn't work.

Comment: @OrnKristjansson In updown.Refresh() the value just blinked and disappeared.

Comment: It worked fine for me after replacing `ControlCollection` with `Controls`.

Comment: What is this? Windows forms?

Comment: Yes it is Windows Forms.

Comment: So,is your problem solved?

Comment: this works fine for me. elaborate your problem. i suspect you're changing value somewhere else too

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413368/how-to-get-value-of-programmatically-created-numericupdown

Comment: Your comment gave me the solution...It was a very silly mistake

Comment: For resetting the textbox i was using
control.text=""; This was causing the problem

Comment: so upvote that comment,as i don't give it as a solution.:)

Comment: I have upvoted it :-)

Comment: Also I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be cleaner to use 'else if' on the last two `if` statments instead of explicitly checking for NumericUpDown:

```
    public void ResetFields(Control.ControlCollection Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                control.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (control is NumericUpDown)
            {
                ((NumericUpDown)control).Value = 3;
            }
            else if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                this.ResetFields(control.Controls);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NumericUpDown` Control has `Textbox` as its child control.
So after the value of the `NumericUpDown` control is changed, it will also get more child controls from it in the next loop and it was resetting the text to empty by checking `(control is TextBox)` condition.

```
public void ResetFields(Control.ControlCollection Controls)
{
foreach(Control control in Controls)
{
   if (control is TextBox)
   {
      control.Text = string.Empty;
   }
   if (control is NumericUpDown)
   {
      NumericUpDown updown = control as NumericUpDown;
      updown.Value = 3;
   }

   if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
   {
      this.ResetFields(control.Controls);
   }
}
}
```

The solution was this change:

```
   if (control.Controls.Count > 0 && !(control is NumericUpDown))
   {
      this.ResetFields(control.Controls);
   }
```

Comment: Good catch.  Someone else's code that I was modifying was using a check to see if each control had child controls before enabling it (to find group boxes, presumably), and it never got around to enabling the numericupdowns.  This would be why.